# "Error: [$resource:badcfg] Error in resource configuration for action `get`. Expected response to contain an object but got an array

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I try to find a contact, with a specified contactPersonId.

The state to find a contact, that works is:

```
.state("contactDetail", {
    url: "/contacts/:id",
    templateUrl: "app/contacts/contactDetailView.html",
    controller: "ContactDetailController as viewModel",
    resolve: {
        contactResource: "contactResource",
        contact: function(contactResource, $stateParams){
            var id = $stateParams.id;
            return contactResource.get({id: id}).$promise;
        }
    }
})
```

Now, when I try to make a more advanced search for the contact with a contactperson in it that has a certain Id, I try to use this:

```
.state("contactPersonDetail", {
    url: "/contactPerson/:id",
    templateUrl: "app/contacts/contactPersonDetailView.html",
    controller: "ContactPersonDetailController as viewModel",
    resolve: {
        contactResource: "contactResource",
        contactPersoon: function(contactResource, $stateParams){
            var id = $stateParams.id;
            var contacts = contactResource.get();
            var contact;
            for(var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++){
                if(contacts[i].contactPerson.id == id){
                    contact = contacts[i].contactPerson;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return contact.$promise;

        }
    }
})
```

When I click on a contactPerson, to view the details of it, I get this error:

> "Error: [$resource:badcfg] Error in resource configuration for action `get`. Expected response to contain an object but got an array (Request: GET http://--url--/api/contacts/)

My questions are: 
Is it even possible how I try to do it? 
  If yes, what's wrong?
  If no, how should it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the documentation for [`$resource`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource), see this line under actions:

> isArray – {boolean=} – If true then the returned object for this action is an array, see returns section.

Basically, you need to specify if your backend is going to return an object or an array, so that it knows how to deal with the data.

---

Update: Upon re-reading your comment, it looks like you you are misunderstanding what `get()` is doing when providing an `id` vs not providing an `id`.

Without seeing your urls, I assume you are calling your backend with something like:

```
http://--url--/api/contacts/
```

&

```
http://--url--/api/contacts/<contact_id>
```

It is likely that the first url returns an array of *all* contacts (hence your ability to loop over the results). Where as the second url will just return a single contact object.

This is why for one of the calls, you will need to specify `isArray: true`.

Comment: I have seen that article, but... In my opinion, I am doing twice the same, returning a contact object. Except for the second case, I use a different condition to find it, so why is it then returning an array instead of an object?

Comment: Well considering this is about a resource, it might help to actually provide your resource definition in your question. Also what does the backend provide for each of the calls?